# How decreasing the effective load impedance in the secondary of a transformer heavily dampens it?

Tags: diodes, transformer, frequency-modulation, demodulation, damping-factor

I am reading the operation of the ratio detector for FM demodulation. It works on the principle of **diode variable damping** (please see the figure [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3Jr2.png)). The capacitor C9 restricts the changes in the amplitude and makes it work as an amplitude limiter along with a demodulator. Its working for amplitude limiting is as follows:

As the voltage increases, currents through diode D1 and D2 increase, however, due to C9 the voltage across the capacitor is constant. As a result of which the effective load impedance decreases. **This more heavily dampens the secondary of the transformer** and the Q factor falls.

How can a decrease in the load impedance heavily dampens the secondary of the coil?
I have tried to search it everywhere but can't get any answer.

Comment: Please embed the picture that has C9 directly into your question. Leave a link to the original question.

Comment: @Andy Please note that I have embedded the figure. However, my question is not linked to the given question, it just uses the same device.

Comment: @Userhanu You need to spend more time on your question. There's too little there and too much assumed (by you) about what we know about the situation. Spend more time helping us understand your perspective about the situation. Please.

Comment: Try simulating a parallel LC circuit with different values of resistor in parallel with it.